# How do I scale up some images html and css

Tags: html, css, image

So recently I've been working on a website and wanted to make it responsive I've been able to make it reponsive for all smaller resolutins but I don't know how to make images on my website scale up

[here is how it looks both p1 and logo are images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqnH9.gif)

I tried a lot of methods availble on the internet but nothing worked

All images are in bootstrap container

```css
@charset "utf-8";
.columnup {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.columndown {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column col-md-12 columnup">
        <center><img src="https://image.ibb.co/fESvOL/Group-1.png"></center>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <center>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column  columnup col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/eidfq0/thumbnail-1.png" class="imaget">
        </div>
        <div class="column col-md-4 col-sm-6 columnup">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/eidfq0/thumbnail-1.png">
        </div>
        <div class="column col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 columnup ">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/eidfq0/thumbnail-1.png">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column columndown col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-md-offset-2 ">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/eidfq0/thumbnail-1.png">
        </div>
        <div class="column columndown col-md-4 col-sm-6 ">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/eidfq0/thumbnail-1.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>
```

here is a little redacted version of my website
So can somebody scale the elements so it looks similar on 720p reslution and 1080p resotion

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking here, could you clarify more?

Comment: If you want to scale something up, you gotta use a good quality image and give it a width in percentages as in img{width:100%;}

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqnH9.gif well look how it looks on 1280x720 resolution well i want it too look similar on 1920x1080 or any other resolution i dont like that empty space when webiste is at 1920x1080

Comment: Issmeil B. I'll try

Comment: If you want to fill up the whole visible screen, then you need to use Javascript or some JS plugins

Comment: oh ummm what javascript i need cuase that width:100% thing i tried it alot but didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Bootstrap front-end framework. Bootstrap already has some predefined layout breaking points, specially for the `.container` class, which in your case wraps your images.

Specifically, divisions (`div`) with `.container` class can take one of these width's, depending on the screen size:

```
Screen size   |   Container size
  <576px      |      auto
  ≥576px      |      540px
  ≥768px      |      720px
  ≥992px      |      960px
  ≥1200px     |      1140px
```

According to the table above, the maximum width `.container` `div` can be is `1140px`, if the screen size is `1200px` or higher.

This basically means that if you open the page in a `1920px` width browser, the `.container` `div` will be `1140px` wide, centered in the middle of the screen.
The images inside the `.container` can only be as wide as the `div` they are in, so they are also limited to the maximum of `1140px`. That means there will be some empty space in between the `.container` `div` and the edges of the screen. `1920px - 1140px = 780px` of empty space!

You want to increase the width of your images to `100%`, so they scale up properly from one end of the screen to another, but you wrapped them in a `.container` `div`, predefined by Bootstrap to be `1440px`, so they will never be able to achieve that. To achieve that goal, you need to get rid of the `1140px` limitation set by Bootstrap on the `.container` `div`.

There's literally hundreds of different solutions to this problem and which one you use really depends on your design goal, which you haven't defined very well, so I can't give you the most appropriate one.

The simplest and dirtiest workaround would be to just override the Bootstrap class with this CSS in your custom stylesheet.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
      max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Then of course, style your images:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```